# Подсчет времени нажатия на кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, переменные

В данном куске кода я отображаю нажатия на кнопки, как можно считать сколько нажата та или иная кнопка

https://gist.github.com/kristina-loh/8e6f9bf7e6edc416ce6f15b149d56309

*Не получилось весь код поместить в вопрос, т.к.:*

> Максимальная длина тела 30000 символов; вы ввели 46286.

Comment: объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите считать - сколько времкни нажата или сколько раз нажата или что?

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit]) прямо в вопрос

Comment: А так, если только по тексту вопроса, то я бы добавил фильтр событий, подключил его к нужным кнопкам и при событии нажатия кнопки мышки начал отсчет, а при отпускании засчитывал разницу. Фильтр событий это метод `eventFilter`, а повесить обработку можно через `installEventFilter`. Если же вы имели ввиду кнопки не как виджеты, то нужно использовать события keyPressEvent и keyReleaseEvent, сохранять нажатые кнопки с временем в словарь, а при отпускании кнопки, удалять из словаря, подсчитывая время

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил словарь для подсчета времени нажатия на кнопку

Обратите внимание на проверку `event.isAutoRepeat()`, без нее не будет понятно было ли одиночное нажатие или кнопка уже была зажата какое-то время

Выделил важные места:

```
class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.prev_key = []

        self.key_by_time = dict()
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)
        # раскомментируйте строку  ниже, чтобы увидеть что происходит
        print(f'[keyPressEvent] {_key}, {event.text()}, {event.key()}, {_keys}')

        key = event.key()

        if not event.isAutoRepeat() and key not in self.key_by_time:
            self.key_by_time[key] = time.perf_counter()
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        if self.prev_key:
        ...

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        _key, _keys = self.keyevent_to_string(event)
        # раскомментируйте строку  ниже, чтобы увидеть что происходит
        print(f'[keyReleaseEvent] {_key}, {event.text()}, {event.key()}, {_keys}')

        key = event.key()

        if not event.isAutoRepeat() and key in self.key_by_time:
            t = self.key_by_time.pop(key)
            print(f'Кнопка {key!r} была нажата {time.perf_counter() - t:.2f} секунд')
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        if self.prev_key:
        ...
```

Comment: Возможно ли как то считать общее время нажатия,а не текущее

Comment: @kristinaloh, сумму времени всех нажатий что ли?

Comment: нет общее нажатие на одну кнопку, то есть чтобы результат суммировался,допустим я жал на кнопку А одну секунду вывелось 1,нажал еще на одну секунду вывелось уже 2 и тд

Comment: @kristinaloh, аналогично моему варианту заведите поле, в него суммируйте значение `time.perf_counter() - t` из `keyReleaseEvent` и выводите то поле в консоли. Возможно, придется как-то хитрее строить логику...